# iOS Debugger unable to type-cast variable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So while debugging, I print out the item, which it says is UITabBarButton. But when I try to cast it as a UITabBarButton, it says that's an undeclared type.

Is there a way to type-cast it, so I can access UITabBarButton's properties?

Here are the two po statements:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `po (nextItem as? UITabBarButton)`? Also, try `p (nextItem as? UITabBarButton)`

Comment: `UITabBarButton` is a private class so I don't think you could cast to it.